# Set Aptana to collaborate with team members on Dreamweaver?

Tags: dreamweaver, collaboration, aptana

I think I want to switch from Dreamweaver to the eclipse based IDE, Aptana. The only real issue stopping me is that I need to be able to collaborate with the other members on my team. Like being able to check-in/out files so we don't override each others work. The other members on my team want to stick with Dreamweaver. So, is there a way to set Aptana to collaborate with team members who are using Dreamweaver?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
If there is no way currently to do this, then I believe there should be a way to program it yourself. For example whenever a file is checked out in dreamweaver a file is created with the same name follwed by .LCK so if you were to check out **file.php** it would create a file called **file.php.LCK** The contents of the file are just **name||email** of the team memeber who checked it out. So if the file is there and the contents is not your name and email then you cannot check it out, if its there and it is your name and email you have it checked out. If you check it out create the LCK file, when you check it in, remove the LCK file. Could there be a way to program this functionality into Aptana/eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did dreamweaver handle collaboration?

As aptana is based off eclipse, you could basically choose whatever source control repository technology dreamweaver could support and install an eclipse plugin for that, I would think.

There seems to be a dreamweaver extension for SVN, and subclipse for Eclipse, so that would be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a ticket in the Aptana issue tracker. Please go there to support the implementation of this feature:

[Dreamweaver Check Out (.LCK) Collaboration Compatibility](http://support.aptana.com/asap/browse/STU-4888)